# Is there an edge to make my weapons magic?

Tags: savage-worlds, hell-on-earth-reloaded

I'm new to Savage Worlds (Hell on Earth). Just went through a fight where I literally had no option to harm a very nasty enemy that could have easily wiped the party; I also had no option to aid my party.

I'm playing a martial arts based assassin, where my GM is allowing me the trapping of using martial arts edges with weapons (arm blades with the stats of bowie knives as an extention of my body). My assassin can pick locks, talk, sneak, climb, and attack in melee, and that's about the end of his skillset.

Well, we came up against a fleshy horror which was utterly immune to normal weapons, and was well capable of one-shotting, with no special weakness or environmental tricks which I was capable of exploiting. After a few huge damage rounds which had no effect, I just started defending, round after round, hoping someone capable of hurting it went offensive (our doomsayer and templar were using their rounds on shaken recovery and heals). I could... stand there and hope for the best. And it was both frustrating and boring. My character has Grim Servant O' Death and Vengeful, so there was no retreat. It was awful. I never want to do that again.

Is there any way to make my weapons or character magical, preferably through an edge, so that I could do damage to those types of enemies? Are there any options beyond accepting the suck?

Comment: Just because you had Grim Servant of Death and Vengeful doesn't mean there is no retreat. Hindrances are not straight jackets and you *always* have the option of not following them (not following your ideals is a hindrance to your character's happiness). Besides, retreating so that you can plan your revenge when you are well-prepared better fulfills the hindrance than staying in a hopeless fight where you can't defeat your enemy.

Answer (score 4):

If you join the Templars by taking Arcane Background (Templar), you gain a sword that can harm enemies normally immune to non-magical weapons, except Servitors. This could be an interesting story development for your character: they were really rattled by this experience and they are willing to join a group that has power against those enemies, even if they aren't fully committed to their ideals (although the Templars may have a thing or two to say about that).

Aside from that, there are no edges available in *Hell on Earth Reloaded* that allow a character's weapon to become magical. It's possible that your GM could allow the Trademark Weapon edge (+1 attack and damage when using a certain weapon). It lists Excalibur as an example, which in some media is magical. So you could work out with your GM that your weapon becomes magical when you take that. However, the Edge does not explicitly make it magical (indeed, some settings have no magic), so your GM may not allow it to count for that.

Also, there is the *smite* power, which increases damage of the weapon. I've always seen it ruled that this also makes the weapon magical, since the extra damage comes from magic. So if any of your arcane characters gains that power, they can cast it on your weapon to make it magical.

Your character could always seek out a magical weapon. Some do exist in the Wasted West (either as a relic or just an enchanted weapon) and it's an excellent plot hook that the GM could use.

I'd also like to suggest that you talk to your GM about how they expected your character to deal with that fight. Were they expecting you to run away because you were outclassed? (If you are coming from a D&D mindset, it can be tough to remember that "balanced encounters" aren't a guarantee in *Savage Worlds*). Was there something magical around that they were expecting you to use? Did they expect an ally to *smite* your weapon?

If they didn't have a plan and your character was just supposed to hide in a corner while other characters fought, calmly discuss your frustration with your GM and work out a solution for the future.

Comment: Already got informed that Trademark Weapon would not count as magical for those purposes. Our party had multiple ways to deal with the fight, but nothing my assassin was capable of was of any help. Apparently a grenade would have one-shot it, and we did have a templar, and a replacement character doomsayer who was freshly minted, and I think it was partially a fight for him to come back and be super useful on. The Shaman in the party couldn't really hurt it but he could at least throw heals. Poison, fire... the smite option; maybe just expressing my frustration and hoping I get thrown a bone.

Comment: @user3542923 While it's good that your GM made a new character feel useful, it's also their job to make sure everybody at the table is having fun. If you weren't, it's best to calmly talk about that with your GM.

Comment: Smite definitely makes a weapon magical. It's one of the most useful aspects of the power in Deadlands.

Answer (score 0):

If you take Arcane Background (Chi Mastery), you can get magical chi attacks that way such as Bolt, Smite, Blast, Burst in Deadlands Reloaded.

At Legendary in Deadlands Reloaded, there is Right Hand of the Devil that makes a weapon you possess into a magic item.

I'm less familiar with Hell on Earth, but allowing these two options from the core Deadlands Reloaded Player's Guide would help with this situation.

Comment: Neither Edge is available in Hell on Earth Reloaded. They may be related settings, but a lot has changed in 200 years. Besides, the Right Hand of the Devil Edge doesn't explicitly say that it becomes magical, thus it's up to GM ruling just like Trademark Weapon.